# Trying to get Italic font working with CUFON and Avenir Font

Tags: javascript, css, cufon

I tried everything. First, I did the standard thing - upload all 4 files (regular, bold, oblique, oblique bold).

So.
Avenir Light
Avenir Bold
Avenir Light Oblique 
Avenir Bold Oblique

Note that I am using the "Light" version of Avenir as the Regular font.

Anyhow.. after I installed this on my website (http://demo.brixwork.com/master/). I tried designating the font-style:oblique to h4 tag through CSS, tried font-style:italic.. and I also tried the  and  tag. Nothing would turn my font to italic font!!!

So then I tried an alternative. I generated 2 separate Avenir font files - one with Avenir Light, and the other with Avenir Light Oblique, and gave the files different font-family names to separate it (Avenir and AvOblique, respectively).

It still loads the upright rigid regular font on the  tag and it's driving me insane! What can I possibly do to fix this?

Comment: Can we see your Cufon.replace call please?